# FAST Query Language Syntax

Tags: search, fast-search, query

I'm running nested Fast Query on SP 2010. Is this syntax correct?

```
 OR (
 string("London", mode="phrase") 
 , string("ullamcorper et blandit", mode="phrase") 
 , AND (string("publish", mode="phrase"), string("following functions", mode="phrase")) 
 , string("service fee", mode="phrase") 
 )
```

Can I use many times operator "AND" inside operator "OR"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It's hard to say if the query is right, but at least it seems syntactically correct :)

You can nest just about anything. Adding indenting when writing it out often helps on reading the logic.